# Why doesn't client's close() of socket cause server's select() to return

Tags: c, sockets, select, tcp

[I asked something similar before. This is a more focused version.]

What can cause a server's select() call on a TCP socket to consistently time-out rather than "see" the client's close() of the socket? On the client's side, the socket is a regular socket()-created blocking socket that successfully connects to the server and successfully transmits a round-trip transaction. On the server's side, the socket is created via an accept() call, is blocking, is passed to a child server process via fork(), is closed by the top-level server, and is successfully used by the child server process in the initial transaction. When the client subsequently closes the socket, the select() call of the child server process consistently times-out (after 1 minute) rather than indicating a read-ready condition on the socket. The select() call looks for read-ready conditions only: the write-ready and exception arguments are NULL.

Here's the simplified but logically equivalent select()-using code in the child server process:

```
int one_svc_run(
    const int           sock,
    const unsigned      timeout) 
{
    struct timeval      timeo;
    fd_set              fds;

    timeo.tv_sec = timeout;
    timeo.tv_usec = 0;

    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(sock, &fds);

    for (;;) {
        fd_set      readFds = fds;
        int         status = select(sock+1, &readFds, 0, 0, &timeo);

        if (status < 0)
            return errno;

        if (status == 0)
            return ETIMEDOUT;

        /* This code not reached when client closes socket */
        /* The time-out structure, "timeo", is appropriately reset here */
        ...            
    }
    ...
}
```

Here's the logical equivalent of the sequence of events on the client-side (error-handling not shown):

```
struct sockaddr_in *raddr = ...;

int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
(void)bindresvport(sock, (struct sockaddr_in *)0);
connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)raddr, sizeof(*raddr));
/* Send a message to the server and receive a reply */
(void)close(sock);
```

fork(), exec(), and system() are never called. The code is considerably more complex than this, but this is the sequence of relevant calls.

Could Nagel's algorithm cause the FIN packet to not be sent upon close()?

Comment: There might be firewalls, nat gateways or other devices that tracks and times out the connection which will cause your server to not see the close(). If you can rule out that, and this happens consistenly that is not caused by network issues, your code has a bug somewhere.

Comment: Are you `close()`-ing the `accept()`-ed socket in the parent process on the server side?

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov Yes

Comment: @nos I would think it possible but unlikely that a NAT, firewall, or router would consistently delete a FIN packet. I've examined the code (which, unfortunately is too large to post) carefully and exhaustively. I think it more likely that I'm not understanding something.

Comment: Next on the list - are you re-initializing your read fd set on each iteration before `select(2)`?

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov Yes. See the code added to the question.

Comment: Next, have you considered printing `errno(3)` and its `strerror(3)`? on `-1` from `select(2)`?

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov The select() call times-out (i.e., returns 0): it doesn't error-return.

Comment: Does commented code bellow ever execute?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25807/discussion-between-steve-emmerson-and-nikolai-n-fetissov)

Comment: @SteveEmmerson If it's feasible, run your code under strace and inspect the system calls that's performed. I'd verify that the client socket really _is_ closed as well, either by using wireshark, or checking with `netstat`(Use external tools, to e.g. catch a file descriptor leak on the client)

Comment: Just a comment to your last question, nagel cannot cause a fin (or rst) to not be sent. Also `(void)close(socket);` is a quite big bug, hopefully that's just a typo here.

Comment: What operating systems are the server and clients on? How did you verify that the clients socket closes?

Comment: @thuovila Both O/S's are Linux, but the code is designed and intended to be portable. I verified that the client must close the socket by inspecting the code. If it doesn't, then the O/S is misbehaving, which I consider unlikely.

Comment: @SteveEmmerson In the code here, it should be (void)close(sock); as (void)close(socket); would pass the socket() function pointer to close()

Comment: @nos Yes, it's a typo. The statement should be "(void)close(sock);".

Comment: @SteveEmmerson What's your evidence that the client is closing the socket at all? Does Wireshark show the incoming FIN?

Comment: @EJP The server logs a message every time the client connects; the client connects multiple times; therefore, the client had to go through the indicated code, which includes a close() on the socket.

Comment: @SteveEmmerson All the evidence is against it. I suggest you sniff to see whether there really is a FIN. There are other possibilities: the socket FD has been dup()-ed, or corrupted before close() was called.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely explanation is that you're not actually closing the client end of the connection when you think you are.  Probably because you have some other file descriptor that references the client socket somewhere that is not being closed.

If your client program ever does a `fork` (or related calls that fork, such as `system` or `popen`), the forked child might well have a copy of the file descriptor which would cause the behavior you're seeing.

One way to test/workaround the problem is to have the client do an explicit shutdown(2) prior to closing the socket:

```
shutdown(sock, SHUT_RDWR);
close(sock);
```

If this causes the problem to go away then that is the problem -- you have another copy of the client socket file descriptor somewhere hanging around.

If the problem is due to children getting the socket, the best fix is probably to set the close-on-exec flag on the socket immediately after creating it:

```
fcntl(sock, F_SETFD, fcntl(sock, F_GETFD) | FD_CLOEXEC);
```

or on some systems, use the `SOCK_CLOEXEC` flag to the socket creation call.

Comment: Your answer is on-topic and good. Unfortunately, the client-side socket is definitely closed. I've added the sequence of relevant client-side calls to my question.

Comment: Does sticking a `shutdown` call into the client just before the `close` affect the problem?  I've never seen a case with a properly closed socket not being communicated to the server.

Comment: Unfortunately, the client is beyond my control for the moment, so I can't test the shutdown() hypothesis.

Answer (score 3):

Mystery solved.

@nos was correct in the first comment: it's a firewall problem. A shutdown() by the client isn't needed; the client does close the socket; the server does use the right timeout; and there's no bug in the code.

The problem was caused by the firewall rules on our Linux Virtual Server (LVS). A client connects to the LVS and the connection is passed to the least-loaded of several backend servers. All packets from the client pass through the LVS; all packets from the backend server go directly to the client. The firewall rules on the LVS caused the FIN packet from the client to be discarded. Thus, the backend server never saw the close() by the client.

The solution was to remove the "-m state --state NEW" options from the iptables(8) rule on the LVS system. This allows the FIN packets from the client to be forwarded to the backend server. [This article](http://archive.linuxvirtualserver.org/html/lvs-users/2008-04/msg00113.html) has more information.

Thanks to all of you who suggested using wireshark(1).

Answer (score 1):

`select()` call of Linux will modify value of `timeout` argument. From man page:

> On Linux, select() modifies timeout to reflect the amount of time not
>   slept

So your `timeo` will runs to zero. And when it is zero `select` will return immediately (mostly with return value zero).

The following change may help:

```
for (;;) {
    struct timeval timo = timeo;
    fd_set      readFds = fds;
    int         status = select(sock+1, &readFds, 0, 0, &timo);
```

Comment: Already done. The "code not reached" section adjusts the time-out value appropriately. As a crotchety old programmer, I favor concision.